# How to remove "Address Bar" box from Street View?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am using Google Maps API version 2, now I would like to remove address bar from Street View. I have not found a solution to remove this address bar despite significant research. Street View is loading in flash version (I have checked this in Firebug), so I can't play any CSS or JavaScript trick.

Please help me to remove this box in Google Maps v2.  I couldn't update it in [Google Maps v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't remove it in google map api version 2; you should have to update it in google map v3; how could you change in flash if they didn't provide any such functionality like that